# Best way to clone java.time.LocalDateTime

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

I would like to create a copy `java.time.LocalDateTime` but it does not have `clone()` method.

What I do is the following:

```
long epochMilli = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();

LocalDateTime createDate =  LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochMilli), ZoneId.systemDefault());

LocalDateTime modificationDate = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochMilli), ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Is there an easyest way to create two LocalDateTime objects with the exact same date-time value?

Comment: Why do you want to clone? And keep in mind that all manipulated instances are naturally new objects due to the immutability feature. So what is your point or intention?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Because `LocalDateTime` is immutable, you can simply reference the same object:

```
LocalDateTime createDate = LocalDateTime.now();

LocalDateTime modificationDate = createDate;
```

Comment: @Eugene Immutable classes are considered as value types, their uniqueness is bound to value they hold not where in memory they are, there is no need to create 2 separate instances. As that `LocalDateTime` instance can't be changed you can have as many references using it.

Comment: @FilipRistic I'll have to agree, my bad here :|

Comment: @FilipRistic but this brings up an interesting question... what should `clone` do for values types than?

Comment: @Eugene This is indeed interesting question, `clone` by standard should return new instance, but not everything should be `Cloneable`. From my point of view, value types shouldn't ever be `Cloneable` as there isn't any usage for making clone of something that represents value, because they end up with same values which again makes them completely same. For example no one would ever clone number 5 to get another 5, value objects are same, they are tied with value they hold not with memory address.

Answer (score 4):

Since a `LocalDateTime` is immutable, [according to its Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) there is no real reason to clone it.

You can just use the same instance, and pass it around without having to defensively clone it and lose performance.

Answer (score 3):

```
LocalDateTime orig = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime copy = LocalDateTime.from( orig );
```

**edited**:
this code will return the same object, from LocalDateTime sources:

```
public static LocalDateTime from(TemporalAccessor temporal) {
       if (temporal instanceof LocalDateTime) {
          return (LocalDateTime) temporal;
       } 
       ...
```

Comment: On my Java 10 this just returned the same object, not a copy.

Comment: Yes,actually, it returns the same object